# I want to create weekly view for daily meal list

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4.1 and I have in my database 'brunches' table which contain brunches for whole year (365 days = 365 inputs), and now I need to create weekly view for my brunches.

I have created a column for date, so I need to show 7 days of meals (ex.: view/week/8).

```
$date1 =  Carbon::create(null, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'Europe/Ljubljana');
$date2 =  Carbon::create(null, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'Europe/Ljubljana');

$startDate = $date1->addDays(7 * $st);
$endDate = $date2->addDays((7 * $st)  + 1);
$brunches = DB::table('brunches')->where('datum', '>=', $startDate)->where('datum', '<', $endDate)->get();
return View::make('admin.teden')->with('brunches', $brunches)->with('st', $st);
```

But now if I select week one, it shows days completely different days I want to show... Can you please help me=? :)